# List of child custom post types lists all custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types, query, child-pages, children

Several of my pages have some "posts" of custom post types as child posts. On these pages I want to list all of the child posts. Therefore I have this code:

```
<?php
$page_id = get_queried_object_id();
function subpage_peek($parent_id) {
    // reset the query, just to be sure
    wp_reset_postdata();
    //query subpages
    $args = array(
                 'orderby' => 'menu_order',
                 'sort_order' => 'ASC',
                 'hierarchical' => 0,
                 'post_parent' => $parent_id,
                 'post_type' => 'kuenstler'
    );
    $subpages = new WP_query($args);

    // create output
    if ($subpages->have_posts()) :
        $output = '<ul>';
        while ($subpages->have_posts()) : $subpages->the_post();
            $output .= '<li><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></li>';
        endwhile;
        $output .= '</ul>';
    else :
        $output = '<p>No subpages found.</p>';
    endif;

    // reset the query
    wp_reset_postdata();

    // return something
    return $output;
}
echo subpage_peek($page_id);
?>
```

Why do this output all of my posts of the custom post type?

## Update #1

This is my solution and it works:

```
<?php
  wp_reset_postdata();
  global $post;
  $post = get_post(get_the_id());
  $child_posts = types_child_posts('kuenstler');
  foreach ($child_posts as $child_post) {
    echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink($child_post->ID).'">'.get_the_title($child_post->ID).'</a></li>';
  }
?>
```

Does anyone know which kind of reset I have to use if I want of course the above code to be in the content body, but also in several sub-navigations which lists all of these sub-posts? At the moment the main loop (see above) works, but in each of my four sub-navigations not the children of page x are listed but the subpages of the main loop.

Comment: Shouldn't `$page_id` be `$parent_id`? Or the other way around..

Comment: Actually these are the same, you are right. But because $parent_id is used inside the function, I used a different name to avoid messing it up.

Comment: Yes, sorry, doesn't make a difference anyways.. BTW `WP_Query` doesn't have an argument `hierarchical` either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My final solution:

```
<?php
/**
  Modified function from wp types with capability of choosing post_status
  Originally located here: plugins/types/embedded/functions.php lines 319-342
 */
function mod_wpcf_pr_post_get_has($post_id, $post_type_q = null, $post_status) {
    $post_type = get_post_type($post_id);
    $has = array_keys(wpcf_pr_get_has($post_type));
    $add = is_null($post_type_q) ? '&post_type=any' : '&post_type=' . $post_type_q;
    $posts = get_posts('numberposts=-1&post_status=' . $post_status . '&meta_key=_wpcf_belongs_'
            . $post_type . '_id&meta_value=' . $post_id . $add);

    $results = array();
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
        if (!in_array($post->post_type, $has)) {
            continue;
        }
        $results[$post->post_type][] = $post;
    }
    return is_null($post_type_q) ? $results : array_shift($results);
}

$children = mod_wpcf_pr_post_get_has($id, $cpt_slug, 'publish');
foreach ($children as $child_post) {
  setup_postdata($child_post);
  if(is_single($child_post->ID) ) { $current = ' class="current"'; }
  echo '<li><a href="'.get_relative_permalink($child_post->ID).'"'.$current.'>'.get_the_title($child_post->ID).'</a>';
}
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

I hope I can help some people with this.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're confusing `WP_Query` with taxonomy arguments. `WP_Query` doesn't have a `child_of` argument, use `post_parent`. and `sort_column` should be `orderby`.

Comment: I tried this, but now $subpages doesn't have posts. In the backend I linked them definitely.
A possible problem could be that if I go to /parent-page/child-custom-post-type I am redirected to /kuenstler/child-custom-post-type. kuenstler is my custom post type

Comment: how do you link a custom post type to a page? there's no built-in way to do that unless you've done it manually or added your own code to do so.

Comment: I used the plugin "WP Types" and checked the option "hierachichal". This should be the same as if I did it manually with register_post_type(). I wanted to fix the permalink problem after this is solved. But perhaps there is a connection?

Comment: I think you'll need to have a look at the WP Types documentation for how to query your related posts. Setting a post type to hierarchical only lets you set a parent of the same post type.